# Heun functions and boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, special-functions

Using the Mathematica Heun functions, is there are simple way to get the solution of the same equation satisfied by `HeunG[z]`, but with the boundary condition $f(z=0)=0$ instead of $f(z=0)=1$?

Comment: Please include code as well. I am not sure that I understand your question yet.

Comment: Roberto, can you briefly explain why you need a solution to the Heun equation satisfying that particular initial condition?

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question. Generally speaking `z = 0` is a regular singular point for the general Heun ODE. And in this point the Peano existence theorem fails (as well as at `z = 1, a, ∞`).

DSolve is able to solve the boundary value problem:

```
eqHeunG = z (z - 1) (z - a) y''[
      z] + ((z - 1) (z - a) γ + z (z - a) δ + 
       z (z - 1) (1 + α + β - γ - δ)) y'[
      z] + (α β z - q) y[z] == 0;

DSolve[{eqHeunG, y[0] == 0, y[1/2] == 1/2}, y, z]
```

However, one should be very careful with the boundary points to get a solution (for example taking `{y[0] == 0, y[1] == C[2]}` will not lead to solution).

Answer (score 1):

```
eqn = z (z - 1) (z - a) y''[
      z] + ((z - 1) (z - a) γ + z (z - a) δ + 
       z (z - 1) (1 + α + β - γ - δ)) y'[
      z] + (α β z - q) y[z] == 0;

sol = DSolve[eqn, y, z][[1]]

(* {y -> Function[{z}, 
   C[1] HeunG[a, q, α, β, γ, δ, z] + 
    z^(1 - γ) C[2] HeunG[a, 
      q - (-1 + γ) (1 + α + β - γ + (-1 + a) δ), 
        1 + β - γ, 1 + α - γ, 2 - γ, δ, z]]} *)
```

Verifying the solution,

```
eqn /. sol // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Evaluating for `z == 0`

```
y[z] /. sol /. z -> 0

(* C[1] + 0^(1 - γ) C[2] *)
```

For `z == 0`, the function is `1` for `{C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 0}`

```
sol1 = y[z] /. sol /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 0}

(* HeunG[a, q, α, β, γ, δ, z] *)
```

Verifying,

```
sol1 /. z -> 0

(* 1 *)
```

The function is `0` in the limit for `{C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> 1}`

```
sol0 = y[z] /. sol /. {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> 1}

(* z^(1 - γ) HeunG[a, 
  q - (-1 + γ) (1 + α + β - γ + (-1 + a) δ),
   1 + β - γ, 1 + α - γ, 2 - γ, δ, z] *)
```

Verifying,

```
(lim = Limit[sol0, z -> 0]) // InputForm

(* ConditionalExpression[0, 
 Element[(-q + (-1 + γ)*(1 + α + β - γ + 
       (-1 + a)*δ))/a, Reals] && γ < 1] *)
```

The requested solution is then

```
(sol = ConditionalExpression[sol0, lim[[-1]]]) // 
 InputForm

(* ConditionalExpression[
 z^(1 - γ)*HeunG[a, 
   q - (-1 + γ)*(1 + α + β - γ + (-1 + a)*δ), 
   1 + β - γ, 1 + α - γ, 2 - γ, δ, z], 
 Element[(-q + (-1 + γ)*(1 + α + β - γ + 
       (-1 + a)*δ))/a, Reals] && γ < 1] *)
```

Comment: Nice analysis @bob-hanlon! 
And generally speaking Mathematica's DSolve is able to solve boundary problem like this:


DSolve[{eqn, y[0] == 0, y[1/2] == 1/2}, y, z]

where the eqn is the equation from your comment. However, one should be very-very careful working with solutions of ODE's at singular points (z=0 is singular for the general Heun's ODE as well as for the Hypergeometric2F1's ODE) as the output of DSolve might be not what was expected.

@roberto-merlin could you please develop further the discussion?

Comment: @TigranIshkhanyan Do you know when will *Mathematica*  handle Painleve transcendents? Can we expect it in 13.1?

Comment: @Artes thank for question! Painleve transcendents will definitely be implemented at some point in the future versions of WL (but for sure not in 13.1). These are important functions plus we're aiming at covering all the main functions from DLMF.

Comment: @TigranIshkhanyan  Thanks for your response.  Painleve transcendents seem to be the last special functions from DLMF to be implemented in WL  and this is why I'm a bit impatient.  I see that we have to wait  much longer than expected.  I'm working on certain nonlinear systems of ODE's which most likely can be solved in terms of Painleve transcendents.   It's a pity  that almost no information of Painleve transcendents can be found at functions.wolfram.com